# WCF Service works in Postman but fails in VB.NET Website

Tags: vb.net, wcf, postman

I have created my first WCF service and it works perfectly, in https in Postman.

Now, I moved on to work with the Service in my VB.NET website and I can't get it to work.

Here is the Web.config from the Service

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="inculdeExceptionDetails">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true " />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have tried numerous things on the client. But the point I am at now, I can initialize the class, but when I go to call a Function on it, I get:

```
The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
```

Here is my current web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_ICustomZendeskWrapper">
          <security mode="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.myDomain.info/Webservices/WCF/CustomZendeskWrapper.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_ICustomZendeskWrapper"   contract="CustomZendeskWrapper.ICustomZendeskWrapper" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my corrected settings:

Service Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="inculdeExceptionDetails">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true " />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client Web.Config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_ICustomZendeskWrapper">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.myDomain.info/Webservices/WCF/CustomZendeskWrapper.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_ICustomZendeskWrapper" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp"   contract="CustomZendeskWrapper.ICustomZendeskWrapper" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your configuration file creates the service by using WebHttpBinding, hence your service works properly over http and https in REST style. we are supposed to use WebHttpBinding to call the service or send http request to the proper URL instead of using BasicHttpBinding.
Under this circumstance, if you want to call the service by adding the service reference, just like your configuration. I suggest you make the following changes.

1. Use WebHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding in client’s
   webconfig.
2. Add the appropriate attribute to the auto-generated operation. [WebGet], [WebInvoke]
3. Add the webhttp endpoint behavior to the client endpoint.

This could work, but I don’t think it is you want. As you know, we call the service succesfully only when the wcf binding type between the server and the client is consistent. Another solution for this case is we create the service by using BasicHttpBinding. It also works well over http and http.
Please refer to my following configuration.
**Server end.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client end**

```
//use self-signed certificate
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
            ServiceReference2.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client("BasicHttpsBinding_IService1");
            var result=client.GetData(234);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Configuration file.**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://vabqia593vm:11024/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference2.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:11025/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference2.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

In addition, we are supposed to add http binding and https binding in IIS binding module.
[image]

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Abraham I used your advice from the beginning.. I still needed to make adjustments along the way, but it seemed to work out ok.